# how to use pregel module in Arangodb using java client driver

Tags: java, arangodb

I am a newbie and using ArangoDB 3.3.9. I am using the arangodb-java-driver to connect to the dbserver. But the driver seemed have not api for pregel, so how do I using pregel module in Arangodb using java program language?

Answer (score 0):

The Pregel API is not yet supported by the Java driver. But you can already use it. See here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/issues/195